# How to compare values of types string and datetime in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table 'Incident' and I'm trying to get count of all incidents resolved in the last 12 months based on 'Resolved_at' column which is of type 'String'.
I used the below query on Kusto:

Incident

| where resolved_at >= datetime_add('month',1,make_datetime(2020,1,1))

| project resolved_at , severity , number

But I'm getting this error:
Semantic error:...has the following semantic error: Cannot compare values of types string and datetime. Try adding explicit casts.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [todatetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/todatetimefunction), for example the following will return `true`:

```
todatetime("2020-12-24") == datetime(2020-12-24)
```